# Azure RBAC showing a filtered list

Tags: azure, azure-rbac

When I'm going to my Access Control (IAM) blade in the Azure portal, sometimes I see a message saying that the portal is showing a "filtered list"

[image]

Why is it so and what is the filtered that is applied? Any way I can see all assignments all the time?

Comment: hello @2d1b, any update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried checking on my subscription and it shows as below :

[image]

**Note :**

Please check if any filter is applied, if applied then please change it as highlighted in the above image.

If any filter is applied then it will show as below:

[image]

Comment: I didn't have any filter, but it seems like when you add a role assignment, it shows as "Filtered" and then if you navigate away and back, it shows correctly.